# FK Constraint error Headache - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

For a project I am trying to migrate an Access database to an SQL database.

To do this I created a linked server with the Access database and created a script that inserts the data from the Access into the SQL database. The created script is made with a try catch for each insert so that the ordering of the tables doesnt matter. To give an idea, below the script for 2 tables (total of 130 tables) that insert the data into SQl:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Rows AS INT

-- ****************************************************************************
-- ID = 1
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from TableInserted where ID = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT '~UpdateDB:'
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            INSERT INTO [~UpdateDB](
            --   [SSMA_TimeStamp],

                [StepID], 
                [SQLInstruction], 
                [Description], 
                [Customer], 
                [InsertDateTime], 
                [InsertUserID], 
                [ExecutedateTime]
            )
            SELECT 
                [StepID], 
                [SQLInstruction], 
                [Description], 
                [Customer], 
                [InsertDateTime], 
                [InsertUserID], 
                [ExecutedateTime]
            FROM [OPS_VSS_LINKED]...[~UpdateDB]

            SELECT @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT
            PRINT CAST(@Rows as NVARCHAR(10)) + ' Inserted'
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO TableInserted( ID, TableName, RowsInserted) VALUES  (1,'~UpdateDB', @Rows)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END

-- ****************************************************************************
-- ID = 2
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from TableInserted where ID = 2)
BEGIN
    PRINT '~VAN SLUISVELD Origineel:'

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[~VAN SLUISVELD Origineel] ON

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            INSERT INTO [~VAN SLUISVELD Origineel](


                [ID], 
                [a]
            )
            SELECT 
                [ID], 
                [a]
            FROM [OPS_VSS_LINKED]...[~VAN SLUISVELD Origineel]

            SELECT @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT
            PRINT CAST(@Rows as NVARCHAR(10)) + ' Inserted'
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO TableInserted( ID, TableName, RowsInserted) VALUES  (2,'~VAN SLUISVELD Origineel', @Rows)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[~VAN SLUISVELD Origineel] OFF

END
```

So this script will only insert data if it hasn't been done yet (check in the TableInserted). If the insert generates error then it will rollback on the specific table.

This all works great but the access database is prety corrupted (cause of bad desingnin).

I am getting 50+ FK errors and I get stuck on this one in particular:

```
Relaties:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Relaties_Tariefnummers". The conflict occurred in database "OPS-VSS", table "dbo.Tariefnummers", column 'Tariefnummer'.
Tariefnummers:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "Tariefnummers$RelatiesTariefnummers". The conflict occurred in database "OPS-VSS", table "dbo.Relaties", column 'RelatieNummer'.
```

Multiple `FK errors` are with the `Relaties` table so I thought lets fix that one first. 
Above you can see the `Relaties` table fails inserting because of a `FK error` on the `TariefNummers` table, this is not strange since that specific table hasn't got it's data in it since that table also has a `FK error`.

So the next logical thing for me was to fix the FK error on the `TariefNummers` table. Though the FK error on the `TariefNummers` is linked to the `Relaties` table... So they are diabling each other.. Any clue how to fix this? Should I just delete 1 FK (on the TariefNummers) which isn't preferred.

I might be way off though, but some pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: When doing a conversion like this, I would remove all foreign keys, migrate the data, then reestablish them afterward.  Trying to juggle the key order on top of dealing with conversion issues is too much work for me.  I bet that there are better approaches, but that is the one I use.

Comment: Well that would mean you would go on with bad data instead of fixing it.. I just want it to get fixed so the data gets fixed once and for all. But yeah I agree, it is a lot of work.

Comment: You would go on with bad data, *temporarily*.  Once all of the data is in SQL server, you can go about cleaning it up using TSQL so that when you reestablish the FKs with CHECK CONSTRAINT, they don't fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be valid reasons to want to have two tables with foreign keys to each other, but how will you ever be able to put data in them in the first place?

To populate the tables, you will have to drop or ignore one of those foreign keys, at least temporarily, until both tables are populated.